# Creating a Purchase receipt from Charges controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm creating a new Purchase from the create method of the ChargesContoller.
I can successfully create the new Purchase and pass the information related to the charge.

**My questions is: How can I get the order id to the Purchase?**

Here' how the checkout process works:
Event > Option > Reservation > Order "has many reservations" >
in the Order show view, I have the Stripe button which creates a new charge > redirect to Purchase.

The Purchase is basically a receipt for the order. That's why I would like to show the order id and the reservations associated with the order. I know is not passing the order id because I can see it in the rails console

Should I use a different kind of association like has_many_and_belongs_to_many?
Maybe a joinTable?

I was reading at this part of the rails guides but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

or maybe is the way I'm trying to pass the order id "in the charges create" to the purchase:

```
  purchase = Purchase.create(customer_email: params[:stripeEmail], amount: params[:amount],
   customer_card: params[:stripeToken], order_id: params[:order_id], customer_id: customer.id)
```

**Order Model:**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :purchase
  has_many :reservations
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_create :create_unique_identifier
  before_save :total_for_no_price
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def to_param
     uuid
   end

  def subtotal
    reservations.collect{ |r| r.price }.sum
  end

  def total_for_no_price
    if self.subtotal.nil?
      self[:subtotal] = 0
    end
  end

   def create_unique_identifier
     self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
   end
private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end


end
```

**Purchase model:**

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :reservations, through: :orders
end
```

**Charges Controller:**

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @order = Order.find_by_uuid(session[:order_id])
      @reservations = @order.reservations

      @amount = @order.subtotal.to_i * 100

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => @order.id,
        :currency    => 'usd'


      )

      purchase = Purchase.create(customer_email: params[:stripeEmail], amount: params[:amount],
       customer_card: params[:stripeToken], order_id: params[:order_id], customer_id: customer.id)



    if charge.save
        @order_id = @order.update_attributes(order_status_id: 2)
        #redirect_to @order
        redirect_to purchase
        reset_session

    end   

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end
end
```

**Orders Controller:**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
    @order = Order.find_by_uuid(params[:id])
    @reservations = @order.reservations
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find_by_uuid(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:subtotal, :tax, :total, :order_status_id, :uuid)
    end
end
```

**Order Show page with the charge button:**

```
<div class="container-fluid events-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <h4>Your Registrations:</h4>
            <% @order.reservations.each do |reservation| %>
            <h4><%= reservation.name %> <%= reservation.lastname %> | <%= reservation.email %> | <%= reservation.phone %></h4>
            <h4><%= reservation.gender %> <%= reservation.shirt %> </h4> 
                <% unless  reservation.team === 'N/A' %>
                    <h4>Team: <%= reservation.team %></h4>
                <% end %>
                <% unless  reservation.redeemcode === 'N/A' %>
                    <h4>Redeem Code: <%= reservation.redeemcode %></h4>
                <% end %>
            <hr>                            
            <% end %>
            <h1>Order Total: <%= number_to_currency(@order.subtotal)%></h1>
            <% if @order.order_status_id === 1 %>
              <%= form_tag charges_path(@order) do %>
                <article>
                  <% if flash[:error].present? %>
                    <div id="error_explanation">
                      <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>
                </article>

                <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                        data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
                        data-description= "Event Registration(s)"
                        data-amount="<%= @order.subtotal.to_i * 100%>"
                        data-locale="auto">
                        </script>
              <% end %>

            <% end %>           
            <h3>Need to Modify you order? <%= link_to 'Back to Cart', cart_path %> </h3>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is. But perhaps `Purchase` should use `has_one :order`? Is there always a one-to-one relationship between a purchase and an order?

Comment: I edited the  post with a more clear question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by changing:
order_id: params[:order_id]  **to**  order_id: (@order.id)
in the Charges Controller

**Updated Charges Controller:**

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @order = Order.find_by_uuid(session[:order_id])
      @reservations = @order.reservations

      @amount = @order.subtotal.to_i * 100

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => @order.id,
        :currency    => 'usd'


      )

      purchase = Purchase.create(customer_email: params[:stripeEmail], amount: params[:amount],
       customer_card: params[:stripeToken], order_id: (@order.id), customer_id: customer.id)



    if charge.save
        @order_id = @order.update_attributes(order_status_id: 2)
        #redirect_to @order
        redirect_to purchase
        reset_session

    end   

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end
end
```